# Beilinson's theorem for fixed stratifications

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, derived-categories, perverse-sheaves

Beilinson's theorem states that for a variety $X$ and a field $k$ the realization functor

$$\text{real}: D^b\text{Perv}(X,k)\to D_c^b(X,k)$$ is an equivalence of categories.

If we only consider sheaves that are perverse with respect to a given stratification, this result becomes false in general, for example, on $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ with the trivial stratification.

However, when I looked over the proof of this theorem in Pramod N. Achar's "Perverse sheaves and applications to representation theory" (it's Theorem 4.5.9 there), I came to the conclusion that the key facts used there are as follows:

- There is always a smooth affine subset $U\subset X$ such that the natural functor

$$\text{real}: D^b\text{Loc}^{ft}(U,k)\to D_{\text{locf}}^b(U,k)$$ is an equivalence,

- If $j:U\to X$ is the embedding map, then $j_*$ preserves perverse sheaves and is exact,
- For every extension class $\phi\in\text{Ext}^n_{\text{Perv}(X,k)}(F,G)$ there exists an affine open $U$ such that $F_{|U},G_{|U}$ are shifted local systems and the restriction of

$$\text{real}: \text{Ext}^n_{\text{Perv}(U,k)}(F_{|U},G_{|U})\to \text{Hom}_{D^b_c(U,k)}(F_{|U},G_{|U}[n])$$ to the span of $\phi$ is injective.

Now assume that our fixed stratification $\Sigma$ is such that every locally closed stratum $S$ is smooth and affine, has trivial higher homotopy groups (so that $D^{b}\text{Loc}^{\text{ft}}(S,k)\to D_{\text{locf}}^b(S,k)$ is an equivalence), and the stratification is good in the sense that pushing forward along any inclusion $j_S:S\to X$ preserves constructibility. **Update:** As noted by Geordie Williamson, one also needs something like "every closed union of strata is the zero set of a regular function on some union of strata". I am not quite satisfied with the way I stated the last requirement, but this certainly covers the case of the normal crossings stratification of affine space.

The proof seemingly goes through in this case, since it is a proof by induction on the number of connected components of the supports of $F,G$, and in our situation these supports are unions of strata, so for each such union of strata there is an open stratum $S$ which seemingly can be taken as $U$ in all three of the above points.

Am I correct that the Beilinson's theorem holds for such stratifications? What makes me skeptical (in addition to me still being barely competent in this area) is that I couldn't really find a lot of literature on results such as these for fixed stratifications, and also there are two exercises in the next section of Achar's book where he asks to prove this theorem for the special cases of $\mathbb{A^1}$ with the strata $\{0\},\mathbb{A^1}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{P^1}$ with the strata $\{0\},\mathbb{P^1}\setminus\{0\}$, in both cases suggesting an ad-hoc argument in the hint.

**EDIT:** As also noted by Geordie Williamson, the second exercise doesn't quite fit in. But still, it seems that the theorem holds for the case of smooth toric varieties with the orbit stratification, which was most interesting to me: the proof goes through for affine charts of the form $\mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}$, and these charts are unions of strata and cover the variety, which allows to patch things up as it is done jn the final step of the usual proof.

Comment: Good question. I would suggest trying to write a proof and see where it goes wrong. In Beilinson's proof a key point is the maximal extension, which exists only when one is extending over a close subvariety which is given by the zero locus of a regular function. Perhaps one needs to add this to your list of requirements. (Note that this fails in the affine stratified case considered in Achar's book, but the realization functor is an equivalence for other reasons; essentially for "algebraic" highest weight reasons.)

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson I will try to work it out. You are right about the maximal extension functor, I might have missed something in this part of the proof. But what do you mean by "this fails in the affine stratified case..."? It seems to me that everything should be okay in the 2 cases I mentioned, since we are extending over a single point, which is a zero locus of a regular section?

Comment: I agree it should be fine for P^1. One just needs to find generators of Perv and show that exts agree on both sides. One of the points of the maximal extension is that it gives objects for which this ext computation is doable in general.

Comment: Also I agree with your earlier comment (now deleted): The issue is that a point on P^1 is not the zero locus of a global regular function.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson I apologize for deleting the previous comment,  I was just completely misunderstanding how the passage from the affine case to the general case worked. In the original proof, one can cover the variety with an arbitrary affine cover, but with fixed stratification one needs the proper pushforward to preserve perverse sheaves. This holds if we have an affine open cover in which every affine is a union of strata. So we can circumvent the problem you mentioned, for example, for P^1 stratified by two points and the complement. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem, if you do end up working through the exercise and decide either way I'd love to hear about it. (Even if you write up the case of toric varieties it would be useful to add a link here.)